# Python regex matching problem

Tags: python, regex

I have been parsing a GraphViz file for a specific identifer using Regex. Here is the typical content from this file:

```
node10 [label="second-messenger-mediated signaling\nGO:0019932", fontname=Courier, ...];

node11 [label="inositol phosphate-mediated signaling\nGO:0048016", fontname=Courier, ...];

node12 [label="activation of phospholipase C activity by G-protein coupled receptor protein signaling pathway coupled to IP3 second messenger\n\

GO:0007200", fontname=Courier, ...];

node13 [label="G-protein coupled receptor protein signaling pathway\nGO:0007186", fontname=Courier, ...];

node14 [label="activation of phospholipase C activity\nGO:0007202", fontname=Courier, ...];

node15 [label="elevation of cytosolic calcium ion concentration involved in G-protein signaling coupled to IP3 second messenger\nGO:0051482", fontname=Courier, pos="798,1162", width="9.56", height="0.50"];
```

Since I am only interested in the **nodeid**, **label** and the **GO identifier** I have used the following regex to match each line:

```
(node\d*)\s\[label=\"([\w\s-]*).*(GO:\d*)
```

I know that it's neither terribly elegant nor very efficient but it got the job done except for the line with **node12**. I have tried using re.DOTALL and re.MULTILINE but to no avail.

Can anyone help me spot the missing piece of the puzzle to make the regex also work with **node12** ?

**EDIT:

Here [1] is a link to the file that contains one of those lines.

[1] http://amigo.geneontology.org/cgi-bin/amigo/term-details.cgi?session_id=7924amigo1292519756&term=GO:0051482&format=dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you match each line, then node 12 will be splitted in 2 lines...you should read the all file or iter between one node and one other...

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are saying. Any way you can be a bit clearer ?

Comment: my bad, sorry ;) i'm saying that the problem is the new line. in normal cases, the line would be 'node11 label[etc]\\n; in node 12 there is \\n\\n. so the regex dont work. you can do:

Comment: q = open('file').read().replace('\\n\\n', '\\n')...now your regex will work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

[`pydot`](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) is a library which parses dot files using `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `\` after the first line of node12 escaping the line ending?

Comment: I have just added a link to the file so you can take a better look at it.